# While cancelling the animation `AnimationListener`'s `onCancel` is not getting executed

Tags: java, android, animation

I have the following code to set a listener to a view:

```
public static void rotate(final View view){
        final ObjectAnimator rotation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "rotation", -5f, 5f);
        rotation.setRepeatCount(ObjectAnimator.INFINITE);
        rotation.setRepeatMode(ObjectAnimator.REVERSE);
        rotation.setDuration(100);
        rotation.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener(){
            int count = 1;

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

                Logger.d("ANIMATION","S T A R T");

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                Logger.d("ANIMATION","E N D");

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                Logger.d("ANIMATION","C A N C E L");
                rotation.removeAllListeners();
                rotation.end();
                rotation.cancel();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
                count += 1;
                if (count == 5)
                {
                    final ObjectAnimator rotationEnd = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "rotation", -5f, 0f);
                    rotationEnd.setDuration(50);
                    rotationEnd.start();
                    rotationEnd.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
                    rotation.setStartDelay(1000);
                    rotation.start();
                    count = 1;
                }
            }

        });
        view.setTag(rotation);
        rotation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
        rotation.start();
    }
```

This works fine, but when I try to cancel the animation by following code:

`mHiew?.ncl_rds_icon?.animation?.cancel()`.

Ideally the cancel method should get called, but I dont see the log output there.

Am I missing anything here?

Oh and I start the animation like below:

`AnimationUtils.rotate(mHiew?.ncl_rds_icon?.animation)`

Comment: Plz mention what is mHiew, .ncl_rds_icon and what is the purpose of using ? to start the animation?

Comment: Its a simple view, mHiew is a LinearLayout with a nested imageview with ID ncl_rds_icon